# Docusign API csharp embedded signing experience

Tags: iframe, docusignapi, signing

I have code that is creating an envelope using a Docusign template, the signing experience opens in an iFrame successfully.  The problem I am having is that when other user's open the embedded iFrame, the signing process is different from mine, in that their documents open up in EDITOR mode.  But when I run my code, the documents open in signing mode.  Is there a setting that I'm forgetting to set?  I am using the same code examples that are provided in the github repository for the csharp code examples by Docusign.

Comment: Can you edit your qs with the screenshots of what you are seeing and what others are seeing?

Answer (score -1):

1. Don't use an iframe
2. If you still are having problems, edit your question to include your source or include the DocuSign API trace.

Comment: According to Docusign documentation (that I have read), there is nothing explicitly wrong with using an iframe. Why is it not recommended?

Comment: Per [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/), it explicitly says to not to use IFrame for embedded signing. With IFrame, user experience is not great for signers especially if the recipient may be using a mobile or tablet.